# Check if database exists using phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

i need check if exists an database creating in my application with phonegap.
Searching lot but i dont nothing found.

I found content just talking about tables that already exist but nothing talking about how to verify that the database created exists.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the `openDatabase` method works transparently, so it'll create a database if it doesn't exist and return it, or return an already existing one. Why does it matter in your case?

Comment: Because I need the bank and the tables are created only when the person opens the application the first time, after that need only enter information that I will receive through the webservice.
It's very important this..

Comment: Did you solve this problem? Why? :)

Answer (score 0):

I followed a path as follows.

```
var db;
function createDataBase(fn){
    try{
        db = window.openDatabase('example.db','1','Example Database',-1, function(){
            /**
             * database first created ...
             *
             * */
            createTables(fn);
        });
    }catch(e){
        /**
         * database already created!!
         * */
        db = window.openDatabase('readyVehicle.db','','',-1);
        if(typeof(fn) == 'function'){
           fn.call(null, db);
        }        
    }
}


function createTables(fn){
....
....
  if(typeof(fn)=='function'){
     fn.call(null, db);
  }
}

createDataBase(function(db){
    // dosomething();
})
```